# CakePHP 1.3.10 element caching

Tags: php, performance, cakephp, caching

I'm trying to get element caching setup for certain elements but no matter what I do I can't get the cache files to write to tmp/cache/view/

Here is the code for the element

```
echo $this->element('carinfo',
array(
    'car_id' => $car['Car']['id'],
    'show_user_info_box' => true,
    'car_display_size' => 'medium'
),
array('cache' => '+1 day')
);
```

I've got all the following settings in my core.php

```
Configure::write('debug', 0);
Configure::write('Cache.check', true);
```

I'm really at a loose end here and the speed of the site is really suffering because of it.

I've also tried all variations of 'cache' => '35000' and 'cache' => '1 day' etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `cache` key/value in to the second argument - elements take a boolean as the third argument, not an array.